# Url image is displaying in simulator but not in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

I am creating a keyboard Extension app. I want to display images in my custom Keyboard, but it is returning me below error

> **Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."**

but when I runs it in simulator it shows me images, 
I've tried AlamofireImage, SdWebImage everything but getting same error message.
App is displaying images, but I am facing this issue in keyboard extension.

Comment: Can you provide the image path as returned in console when this error occurs?

Comment: http://vizapay.com/keyboard/public/storage/images/characters/movies/%E8%AE%A9%E5%AD%90%E5%BC%B9%E9%A3%9E/%E9%A9%AC%E9%82%A6%E5%BE%B7_1529907246.jpeg

Comment: this image is displaying in simulator, but when I run my app in iPhone it is not displaying anything. 
I've also tested image url from google images, and same result,

Comment: Tried this? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497360/3207014

Comment: @sasquatch it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Resolved my issue, I just used the web View in the UIImage area and pass the image url over there. That worked for me.
**Note: if you face the same issue in Keyboard extension then use it, otherwise it is not good approach to use webView to launch image.**